# What's the purpose of dragging the container to the black bar under the viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Under every viewController in xcode there's a black bar (where the file's owner the the first responder is placed) What's the name of that bar?

Anyone, I have a container I'm using and today I've found that I can drag it and place it in that black bar. A new container icon will be added next to file's owner and the container will disappear from screen. I thought that it was just for real-estate reasons but when I fired up my app i've noticed that the container no longer exists.

What's the purpose of placing the container there if it stops working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use that to place any object. These objects will be serialized with the nib, and instantiated when the nib loads. It can act as some sort of dependency injection: you can have a class that implements `UITableViewDataSource`, drag an object of that class there, and connect it as a `UITableView` `dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Interface Builder scene dock](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html), which displays a view controller's top level objects.